# Interpretation Estimates of fixed effects, redundant parameters

Tags: categorical-data, multilevel-analysis

I am doing multi level analysis with SPSS and have some categorical variables as control variables (country, gender).
[image]

As you can see country has a significant effect, but I am not sure how I can report it sufficiently with country 3 being set to zero because it is redundant.

Basically I want to make a table which includes Estimates, Standard error and significance. Can I somehow put country as one variable?

Comment: Check footnote b... SPSS adds the reference class to the output (which is represented by the intercept and is thus redundant, i.e. getting an effect of 0).

Answer (score 2):

Redendant levels are most often called *reference levels* you can just replace 0's in `Estimate` column with *reference level* note or change description of non-refrence levels e.g. `[country=1 vs 3]` or make another footnote under your table saying "Reference levels: country=3, gender=1".

> Basically I want to make a table which includes Estimates, Standard
>   error and significance. Can I somehow put country as one variable?

You can get significance of `country` as one variable. You can't get `Estimate` and `Std. error` for it. Why? Just take a look on `Estimate`'s interpretation. `1.07` for `country=1` means that in this country `OC_A_Total` is on average `1.07` units higher than in reference country (`country=3`), adjusting for `age`, `gender` and the rest of your variables, of course. Similarly, you can say, that in `country=2` it is `1.005` units higher. These two `estimates` can not be collapsed into one (at least if you still wish it to have some clear interpretation).

Comment: I'm calculating the logit manually and I also have this message in SPSS. So are you guys saying that in my manual calculation it should be `0 * Gender` since SPSS says `0b`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid this warning, which is due to the dummy variable trap, you can try re-running your model without intercept.